# The performance and filesize .Rdata vs .rds

Tags: r, performance, filesize

I benckmarked .RData against .rds and found that .RData is much faster to read and write but it takes more space. Does anyone know why? Here is as example

```
library("microbenchmark")

P = data.frame(T= runif(10000000,100,1000), K = runif(10000000,100,1000), L = runif(10000000,100,1000), U= "F")
Results <- microbenchmark(times = 4,
                saveRDS = saveRDS(P, file = "p.rds"),
                saveRdata = save(P, file = "p.RData"),
                readRDS = readRDS(file = "p.rds"),
                readRdata = load(file = "p.RData"))
file.size("p.rds")
file.size("p.RData")
```

Comment: Mine are very similar in size (189,874,053, 189,874,033) ... how much do yours differ?

Comment: .RData is 280,000,310 and .rds is 189,872,780

Comment: Compression maybe?